# how can I make computer based measurement system for voltages from 0 to 24 volts

Tags: serial-port

I want to design computer based measurement system to measure different low level voltages 
the net search suggested for ADC and serial port programming
if someone can help me how to program serial port or if any other mean to create the measurement system

Comment: perhaps this question is better suited to http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably a little beyond the scope of SuperUser since it requires a combination of software and hardware design which would be hard to describe.

But there's plenty of references on the 'Net. [Here's one](http://www.softbattery.net/measurement/index.htm) which closely follows what you describe.